# Creating an array of objects from arrays of nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm trying to create an array of objects from an array of objects in which has nested arrays. The nested arrays are going to be subsituted for the key name followed by a dot:
for example:

```
const data = [ id: 5, name: "Something", obj: { lower: True, higher: False } ]
result = ["id", "name", "obj.lower", "obj.higher"]
```

I could manage to key the nested keys and values, but I can't seem to get the objs from the array.
For example (expected result):

```
const data = [ id: 5, name: "Something", obj: { lower: True, higher: False } ]
const newData = [{id: 5}, {name: "Something"}, {obj.lower: True}, {obj.higher: False}]
```

I have attempted:

```
 getValues = object => Object.entries(object).flatMap(([k, v]) => {
    if (typeof v !== "object") {
      return {[k]: v}
    }
    return v && typeof v === 'object' ? this.getKeys(v).map(s => `${k}.${s}`) : [k];
  });
```

I will be comparing these filtered array of objects with a user data that seems like this:

```
export const requiredKeys = {
  data: {
    id: null,
    status: null,
    summary: null,
    // "updated_by.id": null,
    // "updated_by.firstname": null,
    // "updated_by.lastname": null,
    // "updated_by.username": null,
    // "updated_by.blocked": null,
    // "pillars.pillarsType": null,
    // "student.created_by": null,
    // state: null,
```

Comment: Do you really want to get an array of little objects, each having only one property? That doesn't seem useful. Why not a single plain object with many key/value pairs?

Comment: it is because the sizes will vary, an the user will be able to select only some keys from the main array. I will need to make a comparsion between two objects, and I will filter the values later on, based on the similarity of these two objects

Answer (score 1):

You could map the key/values or the pairs of the nested objects. From this entries get a new objects.

```js
const
    getEntries = object => Object
        .entries(object)
        .flatMap(([k, v]) => v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? getEntries(v).map(([l, v]) => [`${k}.${l}`, v])
            : [[k, v]]
        ),
    data = { id: 1, item: "Item 001", obj: { name: 'Nilton001', message: "Free001", obj2: { test: "test001" } } },
    result = getEntries(data).map(pair => Object.fromEntries([pair]));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```